# SonarLint Binding Error since Version 2.8.0.214 - Project Count out of Range?

Tags: c#, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I am facing an error while binding a Solution to my `SonarQube` Projects. I am using VS 2015 Update 3, `SonarLint` 2.8.0.214 and `SonarQube` 5.6. Also the Update on already bound Projects fails.

I guess this has something to do with the new `SonarLint` Version that I have installed since Yesterday. Before the Update of the `SonarLint` Extension I have not had these kind of errors.

It seems that the Project count is out of Range:

```
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Started
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Discovering solution projects
   Included projects:
   * ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.csproj
   * ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.csproj
   Excluded projects:
   * None (for selected SonarQube project's quality profile)
   You can change the exclusion options via the SonarLint project-level context menu i.e. Solution Explorer -> Select project(s)
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Download quality profile(s):
   Successfully downloaded quality profile. Name: 'HomagGroup Recomended (Roslyn CA)', Key: 'cs-homaggroup-recomended-roslyn-ca-58198', Language: 'C#'
   Installing NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'StyleCop.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'StyleCop.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'System.Runtime.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'System.Runtime.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
Unexpected error during workflow execution: Invalid range. Expected [1, 2]
Parameter name: increment
Actual value was 3..
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Started
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Discovering solution projects
   Included projects:
   * ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.csproj
   * ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.csproj
   * ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.csproj
   * ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.csproj
   Excluded projects:
   * None (for selected SonarQube project's quality profile)
   You can change the exclusion options via the SonarLint project-level context menu i.e. Solution Explorer -> Select project(s)
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Download quality profile(s):
   Successfully downloaded quality profile. Name: 'HomagGroup Recomended (Roslyn CA)', Key: 'cs-homaggroup-recomended-roslyn-ca-58198', Language: 'C#'
   Installing NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'StyleCop.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'StyleCop.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'System.Runtime.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'System.Runtime.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'Microsoft.AnalyzerPowerPack' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'Microsoft.AnalyzerPowerPack' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'Desktop.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'Desktop.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
Unexpected error during workflow execution: Invalid range. Expected [1, 4]
Parameter name: increment
Actual value was 5..
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Started
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Discovering solution projects
   Included projects:
   * ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.csproj
   * ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.csproj
   * ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.csproj
   * ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.csproj
   * ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5.csproj
   Excluded projects:
   * None (for selected SonarQube project's quality profile)
   You can change the exclusion options via the SonarLint project-level context menu i.e. Solution Explorer -> Select project(s)
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Download quality profile(s):
   Successfully downloaded quality profile. Name: 'HomagGroup Recomended (Roslyn CA)', Key: 'cs-homaggroup-recomended-roslyn-ca-58198', Language: 'C#'
   Installing NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'StyleCop.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'StyleCop.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'System.Runtime.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'System.Runtime.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'Microsoft.AnalyzerPowerPack' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'Microsoft.AnalyzerPowerPack' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'Desktop.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'Desktop.Analyzers' for project 'ConsoleApplication2'
   Installing NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project 'ConsoleApplication1'
   Successfully installed NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project 'ConsoleApplication1'
Unexpected error during workflow execution: Invalid range. Expected [1, 5]
Parameter name: increment
Actual value was 6..
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks for your help.

I just cloned the sonarlint-visualstudio GitHub Project and installed the debug VSIX Version. Here is the Output:

```
Unexpected error during workflow execution: 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Invalid range. Expected [1, 1]

Parameter name: increment

Actual value was 2.

   at SonarLint.VisualStudio.Progress.Controller.DeterminateStepProgressNotifier.IncrementProgress(Int32 increment)

   at SonarLint.VisualStudio.Progress.Controller.DeterminateStepProgressNotifier.NotifyIncrementedProgress(String message, Int32 increment)

   at SonarLint.VisualStudio.Integration.Binding.BindingWorkflow.InstallPackages(IProgressController controller, CancellationToken token, IProgressStepExecutionEvents notificationEvents)

   at SonarLint.VisualStudio.Integration.Binding.BindingWorkflow.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<CreateWorkflowSteps>b__5(CancellationToken token, IProgressStepExecutionEvents notifications)

   at SonarLint.VisualStudio.Progress.Controller.ProgressControllerStep.ExecuteOperation(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgressStepExecutionEvents progressCallback)

   at SonarLint.VisualStudio.Progress.Controller.ProgressControllerStep.DoStatefulExecution(IProgressStepExecutionEvents progressCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken).

DEBUGONLY: Binding workflow finished, Execution result: Failed
```

Comment: Could you provide the plugins (with their version) you are using?

Comment: Sofar I use SonarLint 2.7 again - this works [2.7](https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonarlint-visualstudio/releases/download/2.7/SonarLint-2.7.vsix)

Comment: We created the Plugins with the SonarQube Roslyn SDK: desktopanalyzers-plugin-1.1.0.jar, microsoftanalyzerpowerpack-plugin-1.1.0.jar, systemruntimeanalyzers-plugin-1.1.0.jar, systemruntimeinteropservicesanalyzers-plugin-1.1.0.jar, systemsecuritycryptographyhashingalgorithmsanalyzers-plugin-1.1.0.jar

Comment: Could you try to bind to a project with a default quality profile (only the C# plugin)? Maybe on a simple ConsoleApplication just to confirm this is working properly on this plugin?

Comment: Binding with the Default c# Plugin Rules (all 176 Rules active) works fine. (Plugin Version 5.5.0.479)

Comment: The Problem starts as soon I add a Roslyn Plugin to the Profile.

Comment: We have published an RC, could you have a look at it, and provide feedback on it: https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonarlint-visualstudio/releases/tag/2.8.1-RC1

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SVS-123) in our JIRA so you can follow the progress on this issue. We are currently processing it.

Comment: The bug is now fixed and will be shipped into the next version of SonarLint for VS. Thanks for sharing it with us.

Comment: Bug fix released!