# SonarLint Binding Project Count Error since Version 2.8.0.214

Tags: c#, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I have the same problems as the user on the page [SonarLint Binding Error since Version 2.8.0.214 - Project Count out of Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491521/sonarlint-binding-error-since-version-2-8-0-214-project-count-out-of-range).

On your Jira board I found the ticket https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SVS-123 that bug will be fixed in the version 2.8.1.

For that reason I´m interested on the information, when do you plan to release this version.

Otherwise is there a workaround? Is there a possibility to install an older version for example?

Comment: We have published an RC, could you have a look at it, and provide feedback on it: https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonarlint-visualstudio/releases/tag/2.8.1-RC1

Answer (score 1):

We are still working on another issue we wanted to ship within the same version and we will let you know when the fix will be ready. In the meantime, I can suggest to you to either:

- Clone our git repository, compile the code and install the extension.
- Uninstall the current version of the extension. Download and install  version [2.7](https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonarlint-visualstudio/releases/download/2.7/SonarLint-2.7.vsix) and in your Visual Studio options uncheck the automatic update of the extensions (otherwise you will get back to 2.8). Remark: v2.7 doesn't provide the connected mode for VB.Net.

Comment: Bug fix released!